# Jquery tabs width next and prev links

Tags: jquery, tabs

the tabs are working fine but I need to trigger the **NEXT** and **PREV** buttons that currently don't make the **tabs selected**

cloud you help me with that?

http://jsfiddle.net/pmnzT/27/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the existing click handler that you have.  When you click next, manually trigger the click handler on the next tab, by calling `.trigger('click')`.  I also put the changeTab code in a common call, so you don't have to replicate code in the next and previous click handlers:

```
function changeTab(next){
    var tabs = $('.tabmenu a');  // Get tab links
    var curTab = tabs.index($('.selected'));  // What link # is selected?
    var num = tabs.size();  // How many do we have?
    if(next) {
       // If next, add 1 (mod total, allows wrapping)
       newTab = (curTab+1)%num;
    } else {
       // If prev, sub 1 (add total, mod total, allows wrapping)
       newTab = (curTab+num-1)%num;
    }
    // This manually "clicks" the next tab
    tabs.eq(newTab).trigger('click'); 
}

$('.next-tab').click(function(){
    // call changeTab(); 1 means next
    changeTab(1);
});

$('.prev-tab').click(function(){
    // call changeTab();  0 means previous
    changeTab(0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/baKYK/

That being said, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) provides a lot of functionality automatically.  Is there a reason you aren't using it?

Comment: the reason why I'm not using UI is cos I'm already using backbone and fey other things. UI sometimes is conflicting with them